# Finding non-negative Integer solutions to X +2Y +5Z = 12 in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

i have used "for" loop and "if" condition to solve it.
      I am looking for smart and faster solution

Comment: try `expand.grid` followed by `apply`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it is not that hard to solve this by hand.

Z can only be 0, 1 or 2 so noting that the Y term is always even then after substituting Z and reducing the right hand side X must be even or odd as the reduced right hand side is:

- If Z = 0 then we have X + 2Y = 12 so X must be even so using 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 successively for X and solving for Y the solutions are (0, 6, 0), (2, 5, 0), (4, 4, 0), (6, 3, 0), (8, 2, 0), (10, 1, 0), (12, 0, 0).
- If Z = 1 then we have X + 2Y = 7 which implies that X is odd so using 1, 3, 5, 7 successively for X and solving for Y the solutions are (1, 3, 1), (3, 2, 1), (5, 1, 1), (7, 0, 1).
- If Z = 2 then we have X + 2Y = 2 which implies X must be even so using 0 and 2 successively for X and solving for Y the solutions are (0, 1, 2), (2, 0, 2).

We can double check the above via brute force -- we could have used 12, 6 and 2 as the upper limits for X, Y and Z respectively since clearly they cannot exceed those values but since the problem is small for simplicity we used 12 in each case:

```
subset(expand.grid(X = 0:12, Y  = 0:12, Z = 0:12), X + 2*Y + 5*Z == 12)
```

giving the following which does correspond to the hand calculation:

```
     X Y Z
13  12 0 0
24  10 1 0
35   8 2 0
46   6 3 0
57   4 4 0
68   2 5 0
79   0 6 0
177  7 0 1
188  5 1 1
199  3 2 1
210  1 3 1
341  2 0 2
352  0 1 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a generic solution:

```
solve.linear.nonneg <- function(...) {
    args <- list(...);
    if (!all(sapply(args,is.integer))) stop('all arguments must be integers.');
    args <- do.call(c,args);
    if (length(args)<1L) stop('missing rhs.');
    if (length(args)<2L) stop('missing coefs.');
    coefs <- args[-length(args)];
    rhs <- args[length(args)];
    cns <- make.unique(sep='',rep(c(letters[24:26],letters[23:1]),len=length(coefs)));
    can <- do.call(expand.grid,setNames(nm=cns,lapply(coefs,function(x) if (x==0L) 0L else 0:(rhs%/%x))));
    can[Reduce(`+`,Map(`*`,coefs,can))==rhs,,drop=F];
}; ## end solve.linear.nonneg()
```

Some demos:

```
solve.linear.nonneg(3L,9L); ## 3x = 9
##   x
## 4 3
solve.linear.nonneg(3L,3L,9L); ## 3x + 3y = 9
##    x y
## 4  3 0
## 7  2 1
## 10 1 2
## 13 0 3
solve.linear.nonneg(1L,2L,3L,4L,6L); ## x + 2y + 3z + 4w = 6
##    x y z w
## 7  6 0 0 0
## 12 4 1 0 0
## 17 2 2 0 0
## 22 0 3 0 0
## 32 3 0 1 0
## 37 1 1 1 0
## 57 0 0 2 0
## 87 2 0 0 1
## 92 0 1 0 1
```

Your equation:

```
solve.linear.nonneg(1L,2L,5L,12L); ## x + 2y + 5z = 12
##      x y z
## 13  12 0 0
## 24  10 1 0
## 35   8 2 0
## 46   6 3 0
## 57   4 4 0
## 68   2 5 0
## 79   0 6 0
## 99   7 0 1
## 110  5 1 1
## 121  3 2 1
## 132  1 3 1
## 185  2 0 2
## 196  0 1 2
```